# regarding rotating the map in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, rotation

I am facing this problem while trying to rotate the map in my iPhone app

The view gets clipped and rotation also happens. I want to avoid the clipping. Any tips ?

heres the code:

```
viewToRotate.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.8, 0., 0., 1.);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the view gets clipped"?

Comment: @Ole, I mean some parts of the screen is blank...

Answer (score 2):

You need your map rotated in 3D ? If not (which is what I think you need), then just use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` (be careful, as it requires the angle in radians).

Also, if you don't want your map to be clipped, you need to make your map bigger, like in the image below (open in new tab to see it bigger)

http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/4498/calculatemapboundswhenr.png

First, you need to calculate the diagonal of the rectangle (your visible map) as instructed in the image above (which I call "radius" because that would be the radius of the smallest circle bigger than your rectangle).

Second, using the radius, you need to calculate the (smallest) square that will allow your map to be seen without clipping. This square will be used to set the `bounds` of your map (caution: NOT the `frame` - Apple specifies that, when using rotation, you should not use `frame` - just `bounds` and / or `center`).

Make sure this square is centered on the center of your visible map rectangle (i.e. the square should have X pixels above AND below the small rectangle ... and Y pixels left AND right of the small rectangle).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure out the solution?

The only way I could do it was to make the MapView in Interface Builder much bigger than the actual size of the screen area its supposed to cover, then I centered the MapView such that its center was in the center of the narrower viewable area.

Rotation seemed to work similarly to how it works in the built-in Maps app.

My guess is that you have to do this so that the image tiles streaming in from Google cover a wide enough area to "fill in the blanks" so to speak, even if they're not always visable.

If you apply a little math, you could probably programmatically size and position the MapView such that you void clipping, but don't require more tiles than is absolutely necessary.